# How to combine two 48 V DC power sources for redundancy?

Tags: power-supply, lifepo4, redundancy

CONTEXT:

I am building a new system to power my servers rack. There will be 2 separate LifePo4 battery packs of 48 V 50 Ah, each with their own charger connected 24/7. This will act as a UPS.

From there I will then have two 48 V lines for redundancy.

All my computers are DC powered, some at 12 V, some at 19 V, etc. So I will build a little rack that has plenty of regulators like this: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LWXAC5E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LWXAC5E)

Having a separate regulator for each computer will also be an opportunity to separate the circuits so if one machine makes a short circuit it won't affect the others. I will also put voltmeters/ammeters a little bit everywhere.

QUESTION:

How can I combine these two lines of 48 V in a way that:

- both are used equally in normal circumstances (current is balanced)
- if one fails or makes a short circuit all the current is taken from the other without interruption.

Is it just a matter of using 2 huge diodes? What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: What is the specified output voltage range for your 48V supplies (their minimum and maximum output voltages)? How close to 50.0%/50.0% do you want to be when "used equally"? Getting them to share equally may be quite difficult.

Comment: You might want to rethink your choice of regulators. You’re concerned about redundancy but cut corners on a critical item.

Comment: The reliability goals cannot be met until you define the requirements and how single point failures are protected from damaging both supplies.  The one you selected might share easily as wired OR  and higher side takes the load with manual balancing.

Comment: The 48V is only a nominal voltage. Fully charged batteries exceed the 55V maximum input of the regulators you intend to use.

Comment: What battery chargers will you be using? Are those just CC/CVs that will charge the battery or will you be using "smart" off-the-shelf chargers.

Comment: Will these chargers also be providing the power for your regulators (and in turn your computers) to use?

Answer (score 1):

For the batteries alone, two 'diodes' or two of a perfect diode-type circuit (MOSFET) would do the trick.

However, there are few red flags that get raised when reading your setup.

First of all, given that your batteries are LiFePo4, having a random charger hooked up to them continuously may not be the best thing to do, because you depend too much on how each charger operates.  For example, some chargers, once they 'fill up' a battery, won't start again until they are disconnected from the battery and reconnected to a battery that is no longer full.  Even if you use a charger that fills up, then starts again the moment the voltage drop by a small amount, this will keep the batteries fully charged perpetually, which is not healthy for LiFePo4 batteries.  To keep the batteries healthy, you would need a setup that operates them between a 40% to 60% SOC, or similar.  That would require more intelligence on your setup; or you would need a smart charger to work with a smart battery to maintain the SOC at something other than 100%.

But the most important issue with your setup, you have two batteries but all of your other components (i.e., the regulators), are single points of failure, and it sounds like you have lots of them.

You would be better off using a single battery and using dual regulators for each rail, again with the diode setup, to ensure failsafe.  And there are a lot of other details you would need to worry about, i.e., if the "redundant" regulators' outputs are different, will the one with no load still operate, or does it need a minimum load?  Would the diodes interfere with the regulator's control loop? and so on.

Redundant setups often appear simple but as you get into the minutiae, you realize they are rather complicated, especially if you factor probability of failure - for example, what is the likelihood of a battery failing versus a regulator?

You also have to consider what are you trying to protect against, in other words, are you trying to protect against power failure and do an orderly shutdown?  Are you protecting yourself against a component failure, in which case, what happens if you lose power for more than your batteries can sustain you?  And as you allude in your question, you will need monitoring devices everywhere because should something fail, you need to know about it, at which point, then what?  Do you shut down to replace it?  if so, you have just lost your system again, so there goes your 365/24/7.  To avoid this you need hot-swappable parts.  You can see how this can go on forever!

And you may have thought of these things, but I'm mentioning them because if you have not, you need to in order to accomplish the goals you have described.

Comment: If you run a supply as a charger, the only way to control the rate of charge is by depending on the supply to be current-limited, and able to run in this 'overload" condition for as long as it would take the battery to charge.  Generally, you don't want to depend on "emergency" features for normal operation - same goes for using the BMS as your safety net when charging, it is mean to be a second line of defense, not the primary control.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to design a super rough draft of what I would want my redundant power supply to look like for my servers, it would look something like this:

[image: design]
(Consider the arrows as diodes)

The 52.5V power supply would be the main thing powering my regulators along with it also powering my battery chargers so that the lifepo4 batteries will always have their full charge. The main advantage of this is that you will not be cycling your batteries due to your main power supply providing power directly to your regulators. If the mains power goes down, that's the time wherein the lifepo4 will immediately provide power to your regulators. I assume you will not care that much with the slight voltage sag that the batteries will have since the regulators will be the ones cleaning this up to the required constant voltage.

Comment: I don't think it's that much of an issue. I hold my UPS lifepo4 batteries at a constant voltage and it's working just fine. You could design a system that switches off the chargers if it's full, but that's just another point of failure.

Comment: I don't think they're that hard to find. They're relatively cheap, just search for "CC CV buck converter" and you'll see hundreds of it. You will need to adjust the current and voltage to match the battery specs, but as long as you have a multimeter and a flat screw head it's not that hard to do